# C++ expected a type specifier for class object

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

I am trying to create a class object with the header file, but I keep getting this error in the main function.

This is the header file:

#### helper.h

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

class helper {
public:
    helper();
    ~helper();

    void setLabel(cv::Mat& im, const std::string label, const cv::Point & or , const cv::Scalar col);
};
```

and this is the cpp file:

#### helper.cpp

```cpp
#include "helper.h"

helper::helper() {
}

void helper::setLabel(cv::Mat& im, const std::string label, const cv::Point & or , const cv::Scalar col)
{
    int fontface = cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
    double fontScale = 0.4;
    int thickness = 1;
    int baseline = 0;

    cv::Size text = cv::getTextSize(label, fontface, fontScale, thickness, &baseline);
    cv::putText(im, label, or , fontface, fontScale, col, thickness, CV_AA);
}
```

Now in **main.cpp** when I try to create an instance:

#### main.cpp

```cpp
#include "helper.h"
int main(){
    helper* helper = new helper;
}
```

It shows this error:

> C2061 syntax error: identifier 'helper'

How can I define an instance of this class in main? I am using Visual Studio 2015 on windows x64.

Comment: Use a different name for your variable: `helper *h = new helper();`

Comment: Avoid `using namespace` in header. especially when you actually fully qualify types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different name for the variable.

```
helper* obj = new helper;
```

When you use the variable name to be the same as the class name, the class name is shadowed by the variable name.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. However, there are other classes in the code that use the same name (as I did here) and there is no issue with them. I added this class just like them, but this error came up.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad, I can't answer why/how they work without seeing the code.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad  Maybe the other examples have different capitalization?